# Finding the Dual of a Ball

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

not really sure what to do for this problem. I know you're supposed to use the fact that the p norm ball is the dual to the q norm ball but im not sure how to prove it
let 1<p, q<infinity such that 1/p+1/q+1 show that the dual of the n ball of radius p is the n ball of radius q
$$
let\, 1<p,\,q<\infty\,such\,that \,\frac1p+\frac1q=1\,  show\,that \,(B^n_p)^* = B^n_q 
$$

Comment: Please write down the problem statement. What is the definition of ''dual of ball'' ?

Comment: @daw I'm presuming it's the [*polar set*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_set#Absolute_polar):
$$
(B_p^n)^*=\big\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\,\big|\,\sup_{y\in B_p^n}|\langle x,y\rangle|\le1\big\}
$$

Comment: @lonzaleggiera thats correct

Comment: Then I don't believe your statement is correct as stated.  If $\ B_t^n(r)\ $ is the $n$-ball of radius $\ r\ $ with respect to the $\ t$-norm, then by my calculation $\ B_p^n(r)^*=B_q^n\big(r^{-1}\big)\ $.  Your result *would* be correct if $\ B_p^n\ $ and $\ B_q^n\ $ were balls of radii $\ p-1\ $ with respect to the $p$-norm and $\ q-1\ $ with respect to the $q$-norm, respectively. Is that what your statement should be?